# android class path exception

Tags: android, classpath

I downloaded an example pf GLWallpaper, from [here](https://github.com/markfguerra/GLWallpaperExample).
I import the project as the readme file said.
However, I got the "class not found" exception.

```
04-09 22:24:06.281: E/AndroidRuntime(31990): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to
instantiate service net.markguerra.android.glwallpaperexample.MyWallpaperService:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
net.markguerra.android.glwallpaperexample.MyWallpaperService in loader
dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/mnt/asec/net.markguerra.android.glwallpaperexample-1/pkg.apk]
```

I don't now what's wrong with it.  The manifest xml has "MyWallpaperService" already.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="net.markguerra.android.glwallpaperexample"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
     <service android:label="@string/service_label" android:name=".MyWallpaperService"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.service.wallpaper"
            android:resource="@xml/myglwallpaper" />
    </service>
</application>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
```

I didn't change anything from the example code.
and here is part of the "MyWallpaperService" class.

```
package net.markguerra.android.glwallpaperexample;

import net.rbgrn.android.glwallpaperservice.*;

// Original code provided by Robert Green
// http://www.rbgrn.net/content/354-glsurfaceview-adapted-3d-live-wallpapers
public class MyWallpaperService extends GLWallpaperService {
    public MyWallpaperService() {
    super();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

problem solved.
In eclipse ADT17, need to put .jar in "libs" rather than "lib" folder.

Comment: You're not the only one to have this problem. Thanks for this answer, we updated the docs because of it.
https://github.com/GLWallpaperService/GLWallpaperService/pull/6

Answer (score 0):

WallpaperService should be MyWallpaperService.
try this instead in the manifest:

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.service.wallpaper.MyWallpaperService" />
    </intent-filter>
```

Comment: same error.
Also, why would you suggest MyWallpaperService is under package android.service.wallpaper?